# $K_9$ edge colouring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Assume we have $K_9$ graph and $4$ colours. We want to colour its edges and obtain following property:
If we change colours in our colouring, such graph will be isomorphic to the previous one (before colour change). Moreover, such graph is unique respect to automorphism group.
How to do it?

So far, I guessed that every vertice should be connected with 2 edges in all 4 colours (for example 2 blue, 2 green, 2 red, 2 yellow).

Comment: "such graph is unique resection automorphism group" could you precise what you meant here ?

Comment: i made a typo, i meant "respect to"

Answer (score 2):

> *If we change colours in our colouring, such graph will be isomorphic to the previous one*

This implies that each one of the 4 coloured subgraphs must be identical (isomorphic), so you have a decomposition of $K_9$ into 4 identical graphs.

Do you know of any such graph decomposition ?

> Additional help, as you said you need that each vertex has degree 2 in each subgraph. And each subgraph contains 9 vertices and 9 edges.

Comment: We need to decompose $K_9$ into 4 $C_9$ cycles. I have already tried to colour it somehow and even came up with the colouring. The main problem is: having a colouring i swapped some colours to get another colouring and then I tried to rearrange vertices' indexes to get the graph from which i started with, but they weren't isomorphic. I though that meant that it has to be a special way to get these four $C_9$ coloured. I can show an example, if it's not clear enough.

Comment: you have a colouring where each coloured-graph is an Hamilton cycle. There are all pairwise isomorphic, swapping colors doesn't change them. As you said each subgraph is $C_9$, but more importantly is a cycle going through all vertices, i.e. an Hamilton cycle. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_decomposition for a general construction (due to Walecki) decomposing $K_{2d+1}$ into Hamilton cycles (and with an handy example on $K_9$)

Comment: It's not necessarily true that the subgraphs are $C_9$. They could be $3\times C_3$ for example.

Comment: @Joffan this is true indeed

Comment: Thank you! But what about its automorphism group? Having a colouring, let's say Walecki's one, will the automorphism group be unique? I can see one symmetry here but is there another graph (coloured in 4 colours) with identical group?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to achieve most of what you are describing - except I don't really understand your requirement "such graph is unique respect to automorphism group." Each colour is a set of $3$ $C_3$ graphs. ($C_3$ is a triangle so it is also $K_3$).

[image]

My attempt to meet the requirement by decomposing into $C_9$ graphs ran into trouble. If this is possible I would like to see one - update:[@ThomasLesgourgues](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/601841/thomas-lesgourgues) was kind enough to point me at the [Wikipedia for Hamiltonian Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_decomposition) which shows how $K_9$ has such a set of spanning $C_9$ factor graphs. <strike>and if not, it would be great to establish why putting in three such $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{C_9}$ cycles results in the last being $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{3\times C_3}$</strike>.

Comment: It's a classical result that the complete graph $K_{2d+1}$ admits a hamiltonian decomposition. The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_decomposition has an image of the decomposition of $K_9$ into Hamiltonian cycle, as per Walecki. More generally, the complete $r$-partite graph $K(n,r)$ on $rn$ vertices admits a decomposition into Hamilton cycles whenever $(r-1)n$ is even, and into Hamilton cycles and a perfect matching if $(r-1)n$ is odd. see R. Laskar and B. Auerbach *On decomposition of r-partite graphs into edge-disjoint hamilton circuits*.

Comment: Right, thanks, that answers my question about a $4\times C_9$ version. Of course mine is not a Hamiltonian decomposition - each colour is a 3-component graph - but I think it also answers the original question.

Comment: Yes it's a valid decomposition and answer. I just don't understand what the OP meant by "such graph is unique respect to automorphism group" too. I guess depending on the meaning the solution would be either this one or the Hamiltonian one.

Comment: Maybe I should've said it in the beginning, but have you ever heard about $k$-unique graphs? Because the main task is to find 4-unique one. The problem is i don't know the exact definition and can't find in anywhere. The only hint i got from my lecturer was to colour $K_9$ on $4$ colours to get unique automorphism group.

Comment: I've heard of $k$-factors, but not about $k$-unique graphs. Apparently nobody so far is sure what the automorphism hint was about.